# why is the code not summing just the positive numbers?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I am trying to sum just the positive numbers in the following list, but my code isn't doing it, any comments on which line is not right would be great!:

```
given_list3 = [5,4,4,3,1,-2,-3,-5]
total5 = 0
p = 0

for p in given_list3: 
    if given_list3[p] > 0:
        total5 += given_list3[p]
        p += 1
print(total5)
```

I am getting an output of 12, when it is supposed to be 17 of course.

Comment: `p` is the *value*, not the *index*.

Comment: Also `sum(x for x in given_list3 if x > 0)` ?

Comment: @hansolo: you're basically saying "all lines except the first are wrong". But there are levels of wrongness.

Comment: Yes, but a user already gave an answer. Just pointing out a simpler version. That is all : )

Comment: Patrick Chong is a new contributor. I guess trying to learn python. Why not let him learn in his own pace. Doing the pythonic way is maybe not the best for understanding.

Answer (score 1):

When using 'p in' you get all p's in the list. This is not an index in the list.
If you want to use an index in the list use 'while'

```
given_list3 = [5,4,4,3,1,-2,-3,-5]
total5 = 0
p = 0

while p < len(given_list3):
    if given_list3[p] > 0:
        total5 += given_list3[p]
    p += 1

print(total5)
```

Comment: Why using p as index when you could use it a value directly ?

Comment: Very good! So it's just line 5 which is not right – a minimal change.

Comment: @azro Using p as an index is what the questioner is trying. So why not help him understand his own code?

Comment: @Mace Which word of him make you telling that ?

Comment: @azro: because it corrects OP's code in just the right place. If you're going to suggest *different* code, provide an answer using `sum` on a list comprehension.

Comment: @azro Just look at his code and see where he's going wrong there. That's adjusted.

Answer (score 0):

## Value-based loop

when iterating over a `list`, the loop variable holds one value at a time from the list, not a index of the list. The following would print all the values, not their indices

```
for p in given_list3:
    print(p)
```

So what you need is (renaming `p` into `value`)

```
for value in given_list3: 
    if value > 0:
        total5 += value
```

---

## Index-based loop

If you want to access values using their index like `given_list3[i]` you need to make `i` to take all the values from 0 to the length of the list, you can do it using a `range`

```
for i in range(len(given_list3)): 
    if given_list3[i] > 0:
        total5 += given_list3[i]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
sum([i for i in given_list3 if i > 0])
```

or

```
sum(filter(lambda x: x > 0, given_list3))
```

both of them will output

```
17
```

The lines in you code that prevent you from aggregating the numbers is

```
for p in given_list3: 
    if given_list3[p] > 0:
```

you can either do

```
for p in given_list3: 
    if p > 0:
```

or

```
for p in len(given_list3): 
    if given_list3[p] > 0:
```

Answer (score 0):

You were using p as the index there whereas p serve as the value or item. (you just showed us clearly that you know c++ or java lol).
here is what you were supposed to do

```
given_list3 = [5,4,4,3,1,-2,-3,-5]
total5 = 0
for p in given_list3:
    if p > 0:
        total5 += p
print(total5)
```